Flutter: After user login, how to create / store session to check if user is logged in on each additional page. MySql
Completely New to Flutter.  Created a very simple app that allows users to either register and if they are registered they can login.  After login it takes them to a dashboard page.
The dashboard page is unique to all users logging in,  So what do I need to be reading, researching to beable to call on the dashboard page to make sure the user is indeed logged in and also to store thier data so that way I can push to the user thier own custom dashboard settings?
Currently the app asks for email address and password.
Calls php file passing email address and password to DB to see if the email address and password match.  If they do match then forward them to Custom Dashboard.
The problem is that I can't call thier custom dashboard if I don't have thier email address or other data to get thier dashboard settings from the database.
Examples, resources, etc greatly appreciated.

why not use cookies https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Cookie-class.html

I didn't even think about that, I have been looking up shared preferences.  I think the cookie route would be better.

Okay looked into it and it seems like the cookies are for flutter web apps.  App is going to be android and ios.

when the scope of the connection is global you can always check the state of the connection

typically your login endpoint that accepts email and password should return you a token that you can then store with flutter_secure_storage  so that you don't have to login again on each app start.

So the solution that I am using is as follows:  On the main.dart when they enter username and password it sends it to mysql and it returns in json the data I need.  I then use builder: (c) => HomePage(username: data['username'])));  Then on the home.dart I can access the username to pull thier individual settings by doing this:   final String username;  const HomePage({super.key, required this.username});  and now I can do whatever I need to do on the home.dart for that individual user.
